# VMWare Linux image with small footprint

Tags: linux, testing, vmware, distribution

I have an embedded system running on a Linux platform. 
What we want to do now is to test all applications running on a minimal Linux distro in a vmware environment.
I try to find a very small footprint distribution which can be ran in VMWare.
The requirements are really only to have the Linux distro without pretty much any servers since we run DropBear / BusyBox for remote communications.
The smaller the footprint, the more instances we will be able to run on our VMWare server.

Does anybody have recommendations on any small Linux distros/appliances without X, web servers etc etc?
The ones I find contains lots of functionality not needed and are either very old or very large.

Answer (score 4):

[Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org) is renowned for its small footprint base system. Arch adheres to the KISS (keep it simple, stupid) principle.

In the default install, Arch Linux does come without any service or X.

Comment: Look no further, arch is the last stop you'll ever make.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Tomsrtbt](http://www.toms.net/rb/download.html), which fits in a floppy.  [Other floppy-sized distros](http://www.linuxlinks.com/Distributions/Floppy/) are available on the [Linux Links site](http://www.linuxlinks.com/).

Answer (score 2):

DSL. Damn Small Linux

http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/

Comment: DSL still uses Linux 2.4 which is really, really old.  This fact may not matter, but the asker may want 2.6.

Comment: Yes the problem with DSL is that you have to miss out on quite a few things. I guess it is not that well maintained these days.

Answer (score 1):

look here

http://bengross.com/smallunix.html

Answer (score 1):

[Slitaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/) and [TinyCore](http://www.tinycorelinux.com/) would both work pretty well.

Comment: Slitaz can't be installed in Vmware

Answer (score 0):

Plain Ubuntu JeOS runs with about 16 megabytes of memory. This Ubuntu distro specialized for virtual servers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a build of your embedded environment for x86, and run that in a VMware session? Then you would have a matching OS (& libc, kernel version, compiler, etc.) environment, just running on a (potentially) different host processor. That would minimize the potential differences between the test environment the embedded target.